# Nullable enum parameter in C# code generated from OpenAPI v3 yml

Tags: c#, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

The title is too stuffed and rather confusing, so here is a snippet of my yml:

```
openapi: 3.0.2
...
paths:
  /whatever:
    get:
      tags:
      - hi
      parameters:
      - name: status
        in: query
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Status'
  responses:
    200:
      description: Successful operation
...
components:
  schemas:
    Status:
      type: string
      enum:
      - One
      - Two
```

I have a `enum` that I want to reuse, so I use in multiple places, so I use `$ref`. The problem here is that if I generate c# code from this spec it will look like this:

```
public void WhateverGet (Status status = null)
{
     WhateverGetWithHttpInfo(status);
}
```

This code cannot be compiled, `status` must be nullable, so I want the generated code to be `Status? status = null`, and this is where I get stuck.

`$ref` does not allow any sibling values, so I cannot do something like `nullable: true`. I was trying to use `anyOf` and provide my enum OR null as options, but generated code came out even worse.

How can I define my yml so the generated code is correct and I my method has an optional parameter `status`?